# Is this conditional clause grammatically correct?

Tags: conditional-constructions

I remember that some linguistic instances could allow for the so-called mixed conditionals.

Is this sentence Ok?

> If I **can** think of one way to describe the experience of approaching to him, it **was** an act of seeking the help of a stone.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a conditional at all but what Declerck and Reed call a 'relevance conditional': a statement with the external form of a conditional in which the formal protasis (condition clause, *if* clause) does not in fact express a condition under which the formal apodosis (consequence clause, *then* clause is either true or actualized but expresses the pragmatic situation which evokes the apodosis. It may be paraphrased

> The experience of approaching him was an act of seeking the help of a stone. I say this as one way of describing the experience.

There is thus no necessary relationship between the verb constructions employed in the two clauses.

Comment: B Thank you. As it is, does it sound odd or wrong?

Comment: @asef It's fine: a little cumbersome, but that's the sort of thing you get in improvised colloquial English.